# kernel panic after call to get_user_pages_fast

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm getting a kernel panic from the get_user_pages_fast function.

I must to use the get_user_pages_fast and not pin_user_pages since I need to support minimum kernel 2.6.

The main goal is to get a pages from the kernel memory.

What I have missed here?

**Kernel panic:**

```
 [15307.994946] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
 [15307.996126] #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
 [15307.996970] #PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page
 [15307.997800] PGD 80000001158dc067 P4D 80000001158dc067 PUD 1214b5067 PMD 0 
 [15307.998891] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP PTI
 [15307.999479] CPU: 10 PID: 10586 Comm: flint_ext Tainted: G           O      5.12.0-rc1_for_upstream_min_debug_2021_03_01_12_16 #1
 [15308.001271] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS rel-1.13.0-0-gf21b5a4aeb02-prebuilt.qemu.org 04/01/2014
 [15308.003007] RIP: 0010:internal_get_user_pages_fast+0x66c/0xad0
 [15308.003939] Code: 01 02 00 00 48 8b 53 08 48 8d 42 ff 83 e2 01 48 0f 44 c3 f0 80 08 02 48 63 45 cc 49 83 c4 08 48 81 c1 00 10 00 00 48 8b 75 90 <48> 89 1c c6 83 45 cc 01 48 39 4d c0 0f 85 3a ff ff ff 48 8b 45 98
 [15308.006762] RSP: 0018:ffff8881994e3940 EFLAGS: 00010006
 [15308.007676] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffea0006339140 RCX: 0000000002480000
 [15308.008880] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffea0006339140
 [15308.010090] RBP: ffff8881994e3a10 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
 [15308.011302] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: ffff88810b19c5e0 R12: ffff888117cba400
 [15308.012588] R13: 000000ffffffffff R14: ffffea0000000000 R15: 800000018ce45067
 [15308.013902] FS:  00007f4cd063e740(0000) GS:ffff88856b900000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 [15308.015387] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 [15308.016445] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000014b58c005 CR4: 0000000000370ea0
 [15308.017766] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
 [15308.019067] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
 [15308.020327] Call Trace:
 [15308.020857]  ioctl.isra.0.cold+0x3d/0x9a [mst_pciconf]
 [15308.021821]  ? __lock_acquire+0x56c/0x2530
 [15308.022622]  ? find_held_lock+0x2b/0x80
 [15308.023381]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x163/0x690
 [15308.024199]  ? __lock_acquire+0x56c/0x2530
 [15308.024987]  ? find_held_lock+0x2b/0x80
 [15308.025736]  ? do_sigaction+0x11e/0x270
 [15308.026481]  ? lockdep_hardirqs_on_prepare+0xd4/0x180
 [15308.027428]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_irq+0x24/0x30
 [15308.028263]  new_ioctl+0x24/0x30 [mst_pciconf]
 [15308.029107]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x3d8/0x790
 [15308.029864]  ? __x64_sys_rt_sigaction+0x7a/0x100
 [15308.030735]  ? lockdep_hardirqs_on_prepare+0xd4/0x180
 [15308.031683]  do_syscall_64+0x2d/0x40
 [15308.032390]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
```

User space code:

```
int allocate_kernel_memory_page(char* pin_pages, struct mtcr_page_info* page_info,
                                int page_amount)
{
    int return_value = 0;
    int page_size = getpagesize();
    char addrstr[80];


    if(!mf || !page_info)
    {
        return_value = -1;
    }

    // Allocate the page address array.
    page_info->page_address_array =
        calloc(page_amount, sizeof(struct mtcr_page_address));
    
    // Set the requested page size.
    page_info->page_size = page_amount * page_size;

    // Allocate user buffer.
    pin_pages = memalign(page_size, page_info->page_size);

    // Save the start buffer pointer as an integer.
    sprintf(addrstr, "%p", pin_pages);
    page_info->page_pointer_start = strtoul(addrstr, NULL, 0);

    // Pin the memory in the kernel space.
    return_value = ioctl(mf->fd, PCICONF_PAGE_ALLOCATION, page_info);
}
```

Kernel space (the case from switch case):

```
case PAGE_ALLOCATION:
    {
        struct page_info_st page_info;
        int write_permission = 1;
        int page_counter;
        int ret;

        // Copy the page info structure from the user space.
        if (copy_from_user(&page_info, udata, sizeof(struct page_info_st))) {
            ret = -EFAULT;
            goto fin;
        }

        ret = get_user_pages_fast(page_info.page_pointer_start, page_info.page_size,
                                  write_permission, dev->pages);
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps `dev->pages` is null? How is it allocated?

Comment: Incidentally, in `allocate_kernel_memory_page` you do not have to use `sprintf` and `strtoul` to convert the pointer. Just use a type cast: `page_info->page_pointer_start = (unsigned long)pin_pages;`.

Comment: The second parameter of `get_user_pages_fast` should be the number of pages to lock down, not the number of bytes to lock down.